# Can't solve my converting circular JSON error

Tags: javascript, json

I keep having this error: Converting circular JSON.

I can't seem to find the mistake

```
function functie()
{
    var footer = document.createElement("footer");
    footer.innerHTML = "<button id='addButton'>" + "+" + "</button>";
    footer.setAttribute("id", "footer");
    document.body.appendChild(footer);

    $(function() { 
        var naam = $("#naam"),
            beschrijving = $("#beschrijving"),
            vervaldatum = $("#vervaldatum"),
            allFields = $([]).add(naam).add(beschrijving).add(vervaldatum);

    function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
        if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips(n);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $("#dialog-form").dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "toevoegen": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(naam, /^[0-9a-zA-Z-" "]+$/, "Medicatie may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter.");
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(beschrijving, /^[0-9a-zA-Z-" "]+$/, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp($('#datepicker'), /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/|-|\.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\/|-|\.](19|20)\d\d$/, "Datum field only allow : a-z 0-9");

                if (bValid) {
                    if (arr === null)
                    {
                        var arr = [];
                arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
                        var gegevens = [{
                                naam: naam,
                                beschrijving: beschrijving,
                                vervalDatum: $('#datepicker')
                            }];
                        localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(gegevens));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var arr = [];
                arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
                        arr.push({
                            naam: naam,
                            beschrijving: beschrijving,
                            vervalDatum: $('#datepicker')
                        });
                        localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(arr));
                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            annuleren: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });

    $("#addButton")
            .click(function() {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            });

    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
});
```

He gives the error ar this line: localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(arr)); which is located in the 'toevoegen': function() {...}

Can you guys help me?

please no down-voting, I've did alot of research..

Comment: Should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, you simply can't convert DOM elements to JSON.

Comment: oh, thank you! didn't know about codereview's existence ;)

Comment: @FelixKling It all started when I started using jquery modals. Before the modals, I used prompts, and this way worked when I used the prompts..

Comment: If you omit the properties that cause the circularity (like `parentNode`), then maybe. But the question is: why would you want to do that? Have a look at these question to get an idea what to do: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+dom+to+json.

Comment: @FelixKling Because I want the data given by the user in the modals to be stored on an array which is then stored in the localstorage of the browser. Then, I retrieve this array and display it on the screen.

Comment: Sounds like you want to store the **value** of a form element, not the element itself.

Comment: Yes indeed. I want to convert the values from naam, beschrijving and vervaldatum to a JSON object and store that object to my array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the 'vervalDatum' (expiration date), but you're passing the jQuery wrapper. Don't you mean to use $('#datepicker').val()? and get the value from the $('#datepicker') element?

Comment: No, because  $('#datepicker') doesn't have a .val() function. When I alert  $('#datepicker'), it works.
I took this from the example at http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form, and it worked when I stored the data in a table. But when I want to convert it to JSON, it doesn't work.

Comment: I had no clue what $('#datepicker') was, but that doesn't really matter. You want to pass the selected date in the object (gegevens), not the jQuery wrapper. From the API:

    $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );

Comment: @JordyV: Obviously `.datepicker()` is a plugin. Read its documentation to figure out how to get the actual value. If you use jQuery UI then `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );` [should work](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate). If not, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for pointing that out, but retrieving the data from the date is not what causes the problem :s.

Comment: @JordyV: No, it's not the problem, it's the solution. Instead of trying to stringify the jQuery object in `arr.push({ naam: naam, beschrijving: beschrijving, vervalDatum: $('#datepicker') });`, you should get the *value* of the datepicker instead, e.g. something like `arr.push({ naam: naam, beschrijving: beschrijving, vervalDatum: $('#datepicker').datepicker( "getDate" ); });`. Of course you have to do this for all other cases too.

Comment: @FelixKling: I did do this, but I still had the convering circular structure to JSON.

Comment: @JordyV: Did you make the changes for `beschrijving` and `naam` as well? Those are jQuery objects too. As I said, you have to do this for all instances. As long as you get the error you are still trying to stringify jQuery objects somewhere.

Comment: @FelixKling: You were indeed right about the other instances. I didn't know these were jQuery objects too.
Kudos to FelixKling! :)

Comment: @JordyV: Well, you have  `naam = $("#naam")` and `beschrijving = $("#beschrijving")`. Calling `$(...)` always returns a jQuery object ;) At least you figured it out!